# Wildcard searches in Code

Tags: code, search

I've been struggling with finding a working wildcard search in the Code application. Is there a character I'm missing? I'd like to be able to highlight multiple numbered items, replacing the number with a wildcard search, but I'm not sure the function exists.

If I'm being blind, that's fine, if someone gives me the answer first I'll be happy to see this closed.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a regex search functionality in Code.  This works for both local seaches (use the toggle button marked "</>") global searches (use the switch in the dialog).  Unfortunately you need to know something about regex expressions but this information is easily available online.  With the correct regex you can search for virtually any pattern of text and also e.g. limit the search to the beginning or end of a line.

Comment: As an example entering `^\d.*$` as a regex search will highlight all lines starting with a number